# How can I prevent the behavior of swipe backward of browser on mac?

Tags: reactjs, browser, event-handling, mouseevent

I working with nextjs that contain a moveable content. I have an event listener on wheel event and want to move the content of my app through app and when I move it horizontally I dont want the default behavior of browser that swipe backward works.

In windows I prevented by e.preventDefault() but on mac it does not work.